# Stagger css animation with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I wonder if there are any ways to do it. For example I have an animation like this [demo on Codepen](http://codepen.io/huyle2607/pen/Rprebz?editors=0010). After 500ms, the next cube will be animating. How can I make the next cube animate after 1/2 of the first animation time. I know how to make it with **.animate()**, but this time it is **.css()** and I can't find a way to do it. I appreciate it!

```
$(function() {
  $('button.action').on('click', function() {
    $('.wrap .item').each(function(i) {
      var $item = $(this);
      setTimeout(function() {
        $item.css({
          'opacity': 1,
          'transform': 'translateX(0)'
        });
      }, 500*i);
    });
  });
});
```

The next animation will start at 1/2 of the first animation time. Not at the end of the first one.

Comment: did you try to put 250*i, instead of 500*i?

Comment: Why don't use `transition-duration` twice longer than your setTimout `500` number. I mean `transition-duration: 1s`

Comment: @Luka I mean I want the next cube moves after 1/2 of the first animation not after the first animation ends :)

Comment: @disstruct Wow! Thanks. This is a cool way to do it!

Comment: @Huy yes I know. Putting 250*i will do just that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @disstruct suggest you may change CSS and reduce timeout to achieve cool effect. I prepare universal fiddle for anyone who wanna to play with it - 
https://jsfiddle.net/skyr9999/rvknhq1m/

Here's the html:

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>

<button class="action">Action!</button>
```

and CSS:

```
.item {
  display: block;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #cd3455;
  transform: translateX(100px);
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(.49,-0.57,1,.99)
}
.action {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  right: 5%;
}
```

and JS:

```
$(function() {
  $('button.action').on('click', function() {
  var duration = 250; //reduce it to have cool effects
    $('.wrap .item').each(function(i) {
      var $item = $(this);
      setTimeout(function() {
        $item.css({
          'opacity': 1,
          'transform': 'translateX(0)'
        });
      }, duration*i);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: So everything is just about the time of the animation. :)  I misunderstood that! Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

As I got it, you want to start animation sequentially item by item, by make it shorter for each next item so they all will got the destination simultaneously. Take a look at this example. Notice: each animation is not 1/2 of the previous one, but 1/n shorter, where n is number of items, i.e. for seven items it would be: 1000ms -> 857 -> 714 -> 571, otherwise the latest would be too short in my opinion.

```js
$(function() {
  $('button.action').on('click', function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      var items = $('.wrap .item');
      var total = items.length;
      items.each(function(i) {
        var initial = 1000;
        var delay = initial - initial / (total + 1) * (total - i);
        var speed = initial - initial / (total + 1) * i;
        var item = $(this);
        item.css({
          'transition-delay': delay + 'ms',
          'transition-duration': speed + 'ms',
          'opacity': 1,
          'transform': 'translateX(0)'
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.item {
  display: block;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #cd3455;
  transform: translateX(100px);
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: all .5s cubic-bezier(.49,-0.57,1,.99)
}
.action {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  right: 5%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>

<button class="action">Action!</button>
```

Comment: Thank u for your effort! In this animation, all the cubes will end at the same time. That's a whole new level for me :)) Thanks but it's not what I mean. It's way easier than your example! Just like @Vasilij didi. Btw you're awesome man! :)